# Iron Router: Get the name of the current controller

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I know you can get the name of the current route's name with `Router.current().route.getName()`, but how can I get the name of the current route's **controller**?

Here is an example of how I define my controller(s):

```
Router.configure
    layoutTemplate: 'LayoutFluid'
    yieldRegions:  
        "footer": {to: "footer"}
        "header": {to: "header"}


@QuantifyController = RouteController.extend
    layoutTemplate: "LayoutSidebar"
    yieldRegions:
        "footer": {to: "footer"}    
        "header": {to: "header"} 
        "QuantifyMenu": {to: "sidebar"}
    action: ->
        @render()

Router.map ->
    @route "Home",
        path: "/"
    @route "Blog",
        path: "/blog"
    @route "QuantifyIndex",
        path: "/quantify"
        controller: "QuantifyController"
    @route "QuantifyNewProject",
        path: "/quantify/new"
        controller: "QuantifyController"
    @route "Quantify..." #you get the idea
```

FWIW, the reason I need to get this is for CSS purposes. I am adding the route's name as a css class to the body, which means that when defining shared styles for views that use the `QuantifyController`, I need to do `body.QuantifyIndex, body.QuantifyNewProject, body.Quantify...` which means every time I add a new `Quantify..` route I need to also add it to the css which is simply not ideal. If I can get the controller name I can just use `body.QuantifyController {...}` in the CSS which is much more ideal.

Comment: Try **Router.current().route.controller**.

Comment: How are you naming your Controller in the first place?  Supplying a name like you would for a route doesn't appear to have any effect.

Comment: @SG_ `Router.current().route.controller` returns `undefined` for me. Maybe my routes are defined incorrectly? Everything is working like a charm though.. no errors anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! After hours of searching, I found it defined at:

**`Router.current().route.options.controller`.**

Note that if the current controller is the default controller (`RouteController`) you will get `undefined`.

@SG_ your comment helped me get there. thanks again.